# How to set user and admin on different dashboard url in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm working on a project where user and admin are two different login. I want to redirect user and admin to their respective dashboard pages.
I'm not getting how to do this. In database, I created roles column (1 for admin, 2 for user).

I'm not getting how to set send to a different dashboard.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator,Redirect,Response;
Use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Session;
use Socialite;
 
class AuthController extends Controller
{
 
    public function index()
    {
        return view('login');
    }  
 
    public function registration()
    {
        return view('registration');
    }
     
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
 
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
           
            // Authentication passed...
             return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
            // return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
        return Redirect::to("login")->withSuccess('Oppes! You have entered invalid credentials');
    }
}
```

Currently on successful login going only same dashboard. I want to change that and send redirection according to roles.

I have created middleware also, but not getting what exact need to do.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
Use App\User;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {

            $auth = Auth::user()->roles()->first();

            switch ($auth->role) {
                case 'admin':
                        return  redirect()->route('admin');    
                    break;
                case 'user':
                        return  redirect()->route('user');  
                    break;

                default:
                    return  redirect()->route('login');  
                    break;
            }   

         }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and routing will be following

```
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@index');
Route::post('post-login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
```

Comment: `return redirect()->intended('dashboard');` change this not in middleware  we use middleware to protect route not for redirect in your case it will be in unlimited loop if you apply that midlleware

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to create a middleware for redirecting users based on their role.

Just check the role of user after successful login attempt and do your redirect.

```php
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
 
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...

        // Set redirect route/path based on user role.
        $to = $request->user()->role->name === 'admin' ? 'admin' : 'user';
             
        // Redirect user to a named route.
        return redirect()->route($to); // or return redirect($to);
    }

    return Redirect::to('login')->withSuccess('Oops! You have entered invalid credentials.');
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Call to undefined method App\User::roles()"

Comment: How do you fetch the roles of a user? Are you using a package to manage user permissions and roles? If so, what package are you using?

Comment: I am not using any librabry or package. Just created role table with migration

Comment: Then, can you post your User model and show how you fetch roles?

Comment: ,below is my User and role model                                      
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}                                                                          
 class Role extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        // return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}

Comment: Just updated the answer. You should use `$request->user()->role` to get the user's role. Then you can access the `name` property of the **Role** model like this: `$request->user()->role->name` (if the `name` field exists in your scheme).

Comment: In role model i have role id and name. and in user table i have role_id so i want to fetch role_name from role table .

Comment: Then you can get the role name like so: `$request->user()->role->name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Manage different different dashboards for User and Admin URLs Easily using **Gates method also in Laravel**.

[refer and Try to understand this Example](https://www.codecheef.org/article/laravel-6-authorization-using-gates),